# AngularJS + Spring WebFlow - Possible to use together?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-webflow

We are looking to start a new project that uses Spring Webflow. Has anyone out there been able to successfully use AngularJS with Spring Web flow? Can we trigger webflow transitions from angularJS?

Comment: Springs is a backend technology and Angular is a front end technology.  These two should not have any clashes.  A better question to ask is rather would angular work well with what you're trying to develop, i.e is it a form, or game or etc.